# How to get the administrative region (admin_level=4) a place belongs to?

Tags: openstreetmap

Given a node on OpenStreetMap, for example a village or a city like [Chicago](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/153388690), how should I derive information such as the `admin_level=4` region it is located in (in this case Illinois), and the country it belongs to (the USA)?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: See similiar question posted over at: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/81089/how-to-get-the-administrative-region-admin_level4-a-place-belongs-to